# Angular password validation

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular 1.x app I have a password field set as follows:

```
<input class="form-control mb15 ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid-required ng-valid ng-valid-pattern ng-touched" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/" required="required" data-validity-message="This field cannot be left empty" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(''); if (!this.value) this.setCustomValidity(this.dataset.validityMessage)" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" id="password">
```

My password confirm field is similar with a check that the two passwords match:

```
 ng-class="{'has-error':userRegister.password_confirm.$dirty && user.password_confirm !== user.password}">
```

This works but the password and pasword_confirm are only evaluated once the ng-pattern regex is satisfied. So if I enter two short passwords which are invalid, the validation message incorrectly tells the user that the password do not match.

If I debug the value of user.password in my template it only shows a value once it is "valid".

I thought I might be able to solved this by also adding the ng-pattern directive to the password_confirm field but it seems this is not a proper solution.

How can I evaluate the two fields as being equal before the regex is satisfied?

Comment: `How can I evaluate the two fields as being equal before the regex is satisfied?` ← They should not conflict/compete with each other. The normal logic on most forms is to have regex validation (if present) on the 1st password field and then a match check on the 2nd textbox only where you enter the confirmation. Validation should occur when the field is blurred (or dirty if you don't want to wait to show validation feedback until after the user leaves the field).

Comment: @Igor even when I add isdirty to the validation rule, 'password' in is not considered equal to 'password_confirm' until 'password' has passed the regex check. If field is dirty and the two fields match AND regex validation fails the two fields are not equal!

Answer (score 0):

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions
>
> The default behaviour in ngModel is that the model value is set to
> undefined when the validation determines that the value is invalid. By
> setting the allowInvalid property to true, the model will still be
> updated even if the value is invalid.

Or you can just add something like this to your condition:

```
'has-error':... && (user.password_confirm && user.password && user.password_confirm !== user.password)
```

P.S. your code is a bit akward...

Comment: as mentioned I can't compare user.pasword and user.password_confirm because for this to evaluate true user.passwrod must first pass the regex validation. I also want to provide feedback if the passwords do not match regardless of whether the password is in itself valid.

Answer (score 0):

I opted for this solution, probably not the most elegant but it meets my use case:

userRegister.password_confirm.$dirty && userRegister.password_confirm.$viewValue !== userRegister.password.$viewValue

By using $viewValue I can compare the actual imput values of the two fields. If I use the ng-model values the user.password value but pass the regex validation before any value is passed to the ng-model. I want to provide feedback regarding the password/password_confirm without considering if the password is in itself valid.

So:

'password' is invalid
'password_confirm' does not match password and is also invalid

- display message that they do not match.